# React/Redux - Is it safe to massage state before render

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, react-redux

> I'm making Tetris in React/Redux, using [Brandly's non-redux version](https://github.com/brandly/react-tetris) for reference/tips and pulling some utilities.

Let us say I have a store (game board), represented by a 2d array. The values are either falsey or the name of the piece's class (for coloring).

Additionally, there is a second store which represents the next pieces to be played (and includes the current piece which is in play, but not yet set).

Inside of the board component responsible for rendering, the stores are attached to props as so:

```
const mapStateToProps = (state) => {
  return {
    Board: state.Board,
    PieceList: state.PieceList
  }
}
```

my render function looks like:

```
  render() {
    var piece = this.props.PieceList.currentPiece;
    var newBoard = _.cloneDeep(this.props.Board);
    pieceSetter(newBoard)(piece._piece.blocks[piece._rotation], piece._position, piece._piece.className);
    return (
      <div className="board">
        {newBoard.map((x, i) =>
          <Row value={x} key={i}/>
        )}
      </div>
    )
  }
```

Where `pieceSetter` is a utility function to add pieces to a board.

Is it appropriate for the render method to do some data-massage to combine information? In this particular instance, it's adding the "current piece" onto the board for display.

I would like to avoid adding the current piece onto the board's store because of how the movement validation functions are currently handled (the board currently ignores the "current" piece for movement validation and considers where the piece will be, there is no notion of "unplaced piece")

Am I creating antipatterns, or can this be considered appropriate?

Comment: I think amageddian's answer is correct - you want to keep the render method pure and do your data manipulation in mapStateToProps. I did want to note that in redux there is only one store. What you are referring to as stores (Board Store, Piece Store) are actually just properties on a single store which are updated via reducers in response to actions.

Comment: @realseanp I agree and I'm just going to wait a little longer before accepting to see if any other answers filter in to avoid an acceptance-dance. Thanks for the one-store comment, that's something I conceptually understood but mis-phrased due to naiveté and will try to use correct phrasings in the future =)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is preferable to place this sort of logic outside of the render function. You might place that code inside of `mapStateToProps`, for example, and trim down the 
 `render` function to be merely *presentational*.

Also, no need to copy the `Board` object using `_.cloneDeep`; React components and containers in the rendering chain won't  mutate the state of the object in your store.